# Compressing Image Selected From Device Android

Tags: android, android-image, android-camera-intent

In my app, I support using `Camera` to take image and selecting from device. The problem I'm having is `compressing` the image selected from the device. It's so large, when I decide to `Encode` it to `Base64` so I can send it over the network, I get a `TimeOutError`. This is my code below.

**OpenImage**

```
 private void openImageIntent(){
    // Determine Uri of camera image to save.
    final File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "amfb" + File.separator);
    root.mkdir();
    final String fname = "img_" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg";
    final File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, fname);
    outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);

    // Camera.
    final List<Intent> cameraIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    final PackageManager packageManager = getActivity().getPackageManager();
    final List<ResolveInfo> listCam = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(captureIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo res : listCam){
        final String packageName = res.activityInfo.packageName;
        final Intent intent = new Intent(captureIntent);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(res.activityInfo.packageName, res.activityInfo.name));
        intent.setPackage(packageName);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        cameraIntents.add(intent);
    }

    //FileSystem
    final Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
    galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
    galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);

    // Chooser of filesystem options.
    final Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(galleryIntent, "Select Source");
    // Add the camera options.
    chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, cameraIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[]{}));
    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);

}
```

And then **onActivityResult**

```
 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
            final boolean isCamera;
            if (data == null) {
                isCamera = true;
            } else {
                final String action = data.getAction();
                if (action == null) {
                    isCamera = false;
                } else {
                    isCamera = action.equals(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }

            Uri selectedImageUri;
            if (isCamera) {
                selectedImageUri = outputFileUri;
                //Bitmap factory
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
                // images
                options.inSampleSize = 8;
                final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImageUri.getPath(), options);
                profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                selectedImageUri = data == null ? null : data.getData();
                //Log.d("ImageURI", selectedImageUri.getLastPathSegment());
                //Bitmap factory
                BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                // downsizing image as it throws OutOfMemory Exception for larger
                // images
                options.inSampleSize = 8;
                try {
                    InputStream input = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(selectedImageUri);
                    final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                    profileImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    } else if (resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_CANCELED){
        // user cancelled Image capture
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    } else {
        // failed to capture image
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope the function I writes will help you.

```
public Bitmap getResizedBitmap(Bitmap bm, int newHeight, int newWidth) {
    int width = bm.getWidth();
    int height = bm.getHeight();
    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;
    // CREATE A MATRIX FOR THE MANIPULATION
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    // RESIZE THE BIT MAP
    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight); 
    // "RECREATE" THE NEW BITMAP
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bm, 0, 0, width, height, matrix, false);
    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: Come On. I like the Matrix manipulation idea. It didn't occur to me to use that. But, it worked. Thanks.